# Rial Symbol can't be printed to PDF with puppeteer

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, fonts, puppeteer, arabic

I am trying to create pdf of a webpage (let's say https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EF%B7%BC) using puppeteers pdf generation tool. The problem I'm facing is that the pdf cannot show a specific character (﷼, U+FDFC, SA Rial) correctly.

I'm doing the pdf creation in a node.js web service, and one clue I have is, when I run the service on my local, and have it create the pdf, the generated pdf shows every character no problem. Though when I run in on the ubuntu server, the rial character is not correctly printed to pdf.

I've tried installing microsoft fonts via `mstt-corefonts-installer` then refreshing the cache with `fc-cache`, my problem still occurs.

Can anyone direct me into a right direction to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe a font is still missing? Can you try to install some more font packages: `apt-get install fontconfig xfonts-utils xfonts-intl-asian fonts-noto-cjk fonts-liberation fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-indic`

Comment: @ThomasDondorf That's what I'm guessing, though I'm not able to find and install the related font. I've ran the command you suggested too, still missing that sign.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf Btw, also tried with `xfonts-intl-arabic` without any luck too :/

Answer (score 0):

With help of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/439138) I've managed to fix the problem with installing the font `fonts-hosny-amiri`.